# Adjust table column width to keep the text in one line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table

[image]

There is a certain columns that I don't want my text to **wrap/go to the next line**, but I'm not sure how to prevent that.

**Red**

I don't want my text to go to the next line

**Green**

It's okay for it's data to wrap into the next line

---

## HTML

```
<div class="row" style=" margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 ">
        <div id="piechart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10 ">
        <table class="table table-bordered piechart-key ">
            <thead>
                <th colspan="2" ></th>
                <th>Item Summary</th>
                <th>Item List</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="22" ></td>
                    <td width="70" >Incorrect</td>
                    <td width="55" ><span id="pc-danger"></span>/50</td>
                    <td width="100" ><span id="pc-danger-list"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="22" ></td>
                    <td width="70" >Partially Correct</td>
                    <td width="55" ><span id="pc-warning"></span>/50</td>
                    <td width="100" ><span id="pc-warning-list"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="22" ></td>
                    <td width="70" >Correct</td>
                    <td width="55" ><span id="pc-success"></span>/50</td>
                    <td width="100" ><span id="pc-success-list"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I've also tried using the `%` as its width, but nothing seem to work.

How do I solve this problem ?

Any hints / helps will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `nowrap` on `th` and 2nd `td` in the table.

```
.piechart-key th,
.piechart-key td:nth-child(2) {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

To force text to wrap in 4th `td`, you could do.

```
.piechart-key td:nth-child(4) {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

For `width`, suggest to remove `width="100"` on the 4th `td`.

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/st982192/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```css
th,
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td span {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style=" margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px;">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 ">
    <div id="piechart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10 ">
    <table class="table table-bordered piechart-key ">
      <thead>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th>Item Summary</th>
        <th>Item List</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="22"></td>
          <td width="70">Incorrect</td>
          <td width="55"><span id="pc-danger"></span>/50</td>
          <td width="100"><span id="pc-danger-list"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="22"></td>
          <td width="120">Partially Correct</td>
          <td width="55"><span id="pc-warning"></span>/50</td>
          <td width="100"><span id="pc-warning-list"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="22"></td>
          <td width="70">Correct</td>
          <td width="55"><span id="pc-success"></span>/50</td>
          <td width="100"><span id="pc-success-list">Item-inside Item-inside Item-inside</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I leave my width as they are ?

Comment: It's your requirement :)

Comment: Target the 4th-child using tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4)